# Weird exponentiation error

Tags: java, exponential, exponent

So, I have this code, which works fine for the first 4 numbers, but then it gives a wrong number, What's the problem? (I know I can also use Math.pow, but I wanted to try doing it myself first)

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    int number = 98;        
    int result = number;        
    int exponentt = 5;
    int exponent = exponentt--;     
    System.out.println(Math.pow(number, exponent));
    for (int i = 0; i < exponentt ;i++) {
        result = result * number;
        System.out.println(result );            
    }
}
```

Console:
9604
92236816
449273376

Comment: int32 only can store up to 2,147,483,647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your `int number` to a `long` and you will get the right result.

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    **long** number = 98;        
    **long** result = number;        
    int exponentt = 5;
    int exponent = exponentt--;     
    System.out.println(Math.pow(number, exponent));
    for (int i = 0; i < exponentt ;i++) {
        result = result * number;
        System.out.println(result );            
    }
}
```

It's going outside of the range for the int and giving you weird results. `int` can only store up to `2,147,483,647` -- 98^4 is well over that (9,039,207,968)

Comment: And in general use java.math.BigInteger because at that rate long can end up very quickly